# Error while enabling IIS optional feature IIS-ASPNET and IIS-ManagementConsole

Tags: powershell, iis, server-core

I am unable to enable the optional feature IIS-ASPNET and IIS-ManagementConsole. I keep getting the below error

```
Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature : One or several parent features are disabled so current feature can not be enabled.
At line:1 char:1
+ Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName IIS-ASPNET
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature], COMException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Dism.Commands.EnableWindowsOptionalFeatureCommand
```

What are the parent features of iis-aspnet and IIS-ManagementConsole that need to be enabled?

Answer (score 4):

You need to pass the `-All` parameter to [`Enable-WindowsOptionalFeatures`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/dism/enable-windowsoptionalfeature?view=win10-ps#examples) which installs the required parent features:

```
Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName IIS-ASPNET, IIS-ManagementConsole -All
```

Comment: I got a source missing error. Am I missing something in the VM?

Comment: You may need to provide an installation source using the `-Source` parameter, which is going to be the sxs directory of your installation media.

Answer (score 0):

To enable asp.net you also need to install the .net extensibility feature. you could try below PowerShell command:

```
Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName IIS-NetFxExtensibility, IIS-NetFxExtensibility45,IIS-ASPNET, IIS-ASPNET45
```

[image]

To enable ManagementConsole you could use below command:

```
Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName  IIS-ManagementConsole
```

[image]

Comment: This gives me the below error
`Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature : One or several parent features are disabled so current feature can not be enabled.
At line:1 char:1
+ Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName IIS-NetFxExtensibi ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature], COMException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Dism.Commands.EnableWindowsOptionalFeatureCommand
`

Comment: @ShabinMuhammed Could you please share which iis feature you enabled right now?

Comment: It was IIS-NetFxExtensibility

Comment: @ShabinMuhammed I need all the enabled iis feature list. can you access the control panel windows feature turn on and off? if yes you could share the snapshot of iis feature?